# How do I create a single openshift template to create multiple pods (different apps)?

Tags: image, docker, templates, openshift

My application is based on 2 openshift images. I want to create a single template for them to start 2 pod (1 pod for each image). I know that we can have multiple container in single pod but we need to create separate pods for each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have multiple `DeploymentConfig` resource objects defined in the template, along with corresponding `Service` definitions and if necessary a `Route`. For a more complex example involving deploying multiple applications in one go, see:

- https://github.com/jupyter-on-openshift/poc-hub-keycloak-auth/blob/master/templates/jupyterhub.json